How to prevent re-defining of a label?
I'm trying to create a command that will use \label only when such a label is not yet defined:
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{bar}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\foo[1]{
  \@ifundefined{x:#1}{%
    \refstepcounter{bar}%
    \label{x:#1}%
  }{}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\foo{hello}
\foo{hello}
Hello
\end{document}

However, I'm getting this line in the log:
LaTeX Warning: Label `x:hello' multiply defined.

What am I doing wrong and what is the right way to define such a command?
BTW, \@ifundefined{r@x:#1} doesn't help.

labels are written to the aux-file and only defined at the next run. You will have to define your test command yourself.

what is the use case for such a label??? you avoid the error but when you use \ref{x:hello} how do you know without tracing tex's run which object is being referenced?

@DavidCarlisle this is just a toy snippet, my real case is more complex. I rerun the same code a few times and need to make sure \label doesn't show up twice (or more)

still doubt this is what you need but \@ifundefined{r@x:#1}{\global\@namedef{r@x:#1}{}%     \refstepcounter{bar}%     \label{x:#1}%

if your counter is unique to the command you could simply test if it has value 1.

So the idea is to find out  how many time \foo has been celled with other names first?  To assign a unique number to each name?

When you say \label{xyz}, TeX will store in the aux file
\newlabel{xyz}{{1}{1}{}{<counter>.1}{}}

where <counter> is the counter's name of the last \refstepcounter command (respecting grouping). TeX doesn't, at this stage, define any command.
When the aux file is read in, \r@xyz will be given a meaning, but this is unhelpful to you. You can define your own (internal) command.
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{bar}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\foo[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{x:#1}{%
    \expandafter\gdef\csname x:#1\endcsname{}%
    \refstepcounter{bar}%
    \label{x:#1}%
  }{}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Foo}\label{xyz}

\foo{hello}

\foo{hello}

Hello \ref{x:hello}

\end{document}

The aux file is
\relax 
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}Foo}{1}{}\protected@file@percent }
\newlabel{xyz}{{1}{1}{}{section.1}{}}
\newlabel{x:hello}{{1}{1}{}{bar.1}{}}
\gdef \@abspage@last{1}

The output is


I use this snippet from https://stackoverflow.com/a/13805186:
\newcommand{\mylabel}[1]{
    \ifcsname c@#1\endcsname%
    \else%
        \newcounter{#1}\label{#1}%
    \fi%
}

To elaborate a bit and take into account the comments:
\documentclass{report}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{m}{%
  % check if a command named label exists to create only one
  \ifcsname x:#1\endcsname%
    label x:#1 already exists
  \else%
    \csname x:#1\endcsname
    \label{x:#1}
    label x:#1 created%
  \fi%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\baz}{m}{
  % check if label exists and use the corresponding ref
  \@ifundefined{r@x:#1}{label x:#1 undefined}{\ref{x:#1}}}
\makeatother



That's no sense. Why even define a counter here.

@daleif feel free to give a better solution. For sure, this is a bad hack. But a functional one!

That make no sense. You are not testing if a label exists but if a counter exists.

Even if it's written 'check if label exists', obviously the test is on a counter associated to the label. I agree it's not optimal, but please elaborate on the 'That's no sense'…

I'd say it is wrong rather than not optimal. In classic tex you would run out of counters pretty quickly in etex less quickly but why use a counter if all you need to test is a csname?

@DavidCarlisle Thanks for the explanation. Does it improve the hack if I replace the counter by \csname x:#1\endcsname (and changing the test accordingly)? Or I'll face the same memory barrier?

yes globaly define it (to anything)

@DavidCarlisle, does the edit improve the hack?

you need a global definition i think
